# Informix change CASE WHEN eventType = 7 THEN "Logged Out"

Tags: database, casting, case, informix

How do I go about in Informix DB to change a int to a string.
Example:

```
CASE WHEN eventType = 7 THEN "Logged Out"
```

Basically when eventType is 7 display 'Logged Out'.

Comment: The syntax is the pretty much standard.  The main question is 'what to show when the event type is not 7'.  If you have lots of mappings, maybe you create a mapping table: `CREATE TABLE int_string_mapping(number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL); INSERT INTO int_string_mapping VALUES(7, 'Logged Out'); …` and so on.  Then use that, probably with a LEFT {OUTER} JOIN, to do the mapping?  It may or may not be better.

Comment: If the CASE causes any trouble, you need to identify reasonably precisely which version of Informix you are using and where you are using it — perhaps 7.31.UC3 on HP-UX 9.8 PA-RISC or something equally devious and antiquated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   case 
      when eventType = 7 then "Logged Out"
      else "Something else"
   end status
from
   table1
where
   whatever = something
```

You will be able to reference the returned column with your text as 'status'.

Answer (score 0):

If the version of Informix you have doesn't support `CASE`, then it won't support `DECODE` either (but it would have to be *seriously* ancient). If you have a small handful of options, you can write a `CASE` statement quite succinctly with `DECODE()`:

`SELECT DECODE(eventType, 7, "Logged Out", 5, "Something", "Something Else")`

Arguments are the column, then pairs of keys and values, then (optionally) a default if no keys match. If you don't provide a default you'll get `NULL` in this scenario.

That said, if you find yourself writing this code over and over, you should create a look-up table for decoding eventType, or at the very least encapsulate the logic in a stored procedure so it only needs to be changed in one place.